# Using Tomcat Web Container in Enterprise

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, containers

We are implementing enterprise portal for one of our client. As part of architecture evaluation we are considering number of web containers - Apache Tomcat being one of them.

There are number of Tomcat based enterprise solutions emerging in J2EE arena, to name some of them:

- Enterprise Tomcat server from Spring Source
- TCat server from Mule Source
- IBM WebSphere Community Edition Tomcat Container
- JBoss Web Server based on Tomcat

We have seen there are certain enterprise extensions provided by these distributions to make Tomcat more robust and enterprise ready. These extensions are in following areas:

- Connection pooling
- Management Extensions
- Thread pooling and IO extensions
- Configuration extensions

Would like to know the experience on these (or if there are any other enterprise distribution) and also are there any enterprise extensions available - such as connection pools, management extensions or secure configuration extensions

Comment: You don't mention any of your requirements though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I also suggest [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/) server as an alternative (former SpringSource dm Server). This is an OSGi container that uses Tomcat for the web front end. You can easily install the extensions you need as OSGi bundles. It isn't a full J2EE container and you can skip the things you don't need.

In general, if you need some of the full J2EE capabilities, it would be better to go with a full J2EE container that offers them out of the box, than trying to add them to Tomcat somehow. OSGi containers offer an alternative, as they allow you to easily manage the features you need.

Comment: Thanks @kgiannakakis, we are in process of evaluating Eclipse Virgo also - do you know any enterprise application or have any experince on stability of the same

Answer (score 0):

I developed enterprise web solutions with J2EE for the last eight years and had no problem using the open source [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) solution. Using database access, you should use connection pooling, but [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) does its work. I also used MBeans accessible  by the jconsole in the tomcat (using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) @ManagedResource), The tomcat has also Thread pooling like any J2EE implementation.

From my experience, most of the "commercial" versions exist to create consulting needs (it is nearly impossible to install a WebSphere  without a IBM consultant ;-)

Comment: Agree - Tomcat does have all the features, we are trying to see if there are extensions to probably extend these features using better implementations - for example, Tomcat uses DBCP - there are Connection Pooling implementations such as Proxool, C3P0, BoneCP that can be considered. Apache's distribution of Tomcat stores datasource password in plain text format in config.xml file - in  enterprise deployments this becomes a security concern. We are trying to find Tomcat extensions that can address to such issues.